# C++ SFML 2.2 graphics not rendering

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm just playing around with C++ SFML stuff and I kinda don't understand why my code isn't working. The thing I want to do is to draw like let's say 5, squares in Window randomly placed around the screen using vector, but I don't understand why it's not working. And it doesn't give any error as well, I can open game like normal, but it's just not rendering.

This is the main game class:

```
#include "main_game.h"
#include "main_menu.h"

void main_game::Initialize(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    this->Player = new player();
    this->Player->setOrigin(this->Player->getGlobalBounds().width / 2, this->Player->getGlobalBounds().height / 2);

    this->TestObject = new testObject();
    this->TestObject->Initialize();
    this->TestObject->setOrigin(this->TestObject->getGlobalBounds().width / 2, this->TestObject->getGlobalBounds().height / 2);
}

void main_game::Update(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    this->Player->setPosition(sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window).x, sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window).y);
    this->Player->Update();

    if (this->Player->CheckCollision(TestObject))
    {
        this->TestObject->setColor(sf::Color::Red);
    }
    else
    {
        this->TestObject->setColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Escape))
    {
        coreState.SetState(new main_menu());
    }
}

void main_game::Render(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites)
{
    this->TestObject->Render(*window, sprites);

    window->draw(*this->Player);
}

void main_game::Destroy(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    delete this->Player;
    delete this->TestObject;
}
```

This is the testObject.h class

```
#pragma once

#include "entity.h"

class testObject : public Entity
{
public:
    testObject();
    void Initialize();
    void Render(sf::RenderWindow &window, std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites);
    void Update();
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
};
```

And this is testObject.cpp class

```
#include "testObject.h"

testObject::testObject()
{
    this->Load("testObject.png");
}

void testObject::Initialize()
{
    sf::Texture testObjectTexture;
    sf::Sprite testObjectSprite;

    testObjectTexture.loadFromFile("testObject.png");
    testObjectSprite.setTexture(testObjectTexture);

    std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites(5, sf::Sprite(testObjectSprite));

    srand(time(0));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++)
    {
        sprites[i].setPosition(1 + (rand() % 1024 - 32), rand() % 640 - 32);
    }
}

void testObject::Render(sf::RenderWindow &window, std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++)
    {
        window.draw(sprites[i]);
    }
}

void testObject::Update()
{
    Entity::Update();
}
```

main_game.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "game_state.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "testObject.h"

class main_game : public tiny_state
{
public:
    void Initialize(sf::RenderWindow* window);
    void Update(sf::RenderWindow* window);
    void Render(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites);
    void Destroy(sf::RenderWindow* window);
private:
    player* Player;
    testObject* TestObject;
};
```

Comment: Did you already inspect this code with the debugger? If not, please do so first, and report the particular anomalies you see in you question.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what exactly is happening without the `main_game.h` to guide us. From my experience, I'd guess it's a scope error.

Comment: I added main_game.h as well.

Comment: There's an obvious problem in testObject::Initialize() where you create a local Texture and assign it to your sprite. testObjectTexture will be destructed at the end of the Initialize scope, and the test object sprite will only ever render as a white box. Create a texture manager object for your textures to live in instead.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix to this is simply use an array, or any other data structure that can store by copy rather than store by reference instead of a vector, which stores by reference, to hold the sprites.

The problem is two fold, its not just a scope issue, if you moved the render function into the initialize scope, you will draw your sprite 5 times in the same place, because every element in your vector is pointing to testObjectSprite's memory location (the same place).